# How am I able to post status on my website members' Facebook profiles?

Tags: facebook, post, profile, status

How am I able to post the status on my website members' Facebook profiles as my website?

This is my code for [Facebook Connect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_Platform#Facebook_Connect), and I wanted to get a permission from the user for me to post on the friends of users also.

```
<div id="fb-root">
</div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js">
</script>
<script>
    FB.init({ appId: '192688544176011', cookie: true, status: true, xfbml: true });
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function () { window.location = "http://www.shijuthomas.in/blogs-about-immigration/";      });
</script>
<fb:login-button length="long" onlogin="signface_login();" autologoutlink="true">
</fb:login-button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the `FB.login` call to establish an [OAuth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth) session with the user and ask for the appropriate permission. Take a look at *[FB.login](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/?_fb_noscript=1)* (SDK Reference).

Comment: thank u very much for the answer..but where do i add the code. FB.login(function(response) {
   // handle the response
 }, {scope: 'email,user_likes'});